# How to send email to specific subscriber from the topic in AWS SNS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, email, boto3, amazon-sns

I have created one topic in AWS SNS. This topic contains many subscribers whose Protocol is Email and whose Endpoint is their email address. I have one API in Django which will send the email to the current user. So for this, I will fetch all the subscribers from the topic and match the email. If a match is found, I want to send an email to that particular subscriber. If a match is not found, I will create a new subscriber with that email address and send an email to it. I want to know how can we do that. What should be written in self.sns_client.publish() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach sounds like it would work.

You would start by calling [`list_subscriptions_by_topic()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns/client/list_subscriptions_by_topic.html).

You can add a subscriber with [`subscribe()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns/client/subscribe.html).

While Amazon SNS is not specifically designed to "send to a single subscriber" you could use [Amazon SNS message filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-filtering.html) to filter the recipients against **message attributes**. Then, when you want to publish the 'single recipient' message you would set the message attributes to a particular value that would match only that subscriber.

Every existing and future subscriber would need a [Filter Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/example-filter-policies.html) that determines whether they should receive each message. You could probably pass an attribute that either contains a specific email address or `'everyone'`. Then, the filter policy could check that the attribute either matches a specific email address or 'everyone'.

Also, be aware that Amazon SNS messages do not make pretty emails. Make sure you are satisfied with the content of an email sent from SNS before investing too much time in this approach.

Comment: Thank you. It works as per my requirement.